# Wrong output using replaceAll()

Tags: java

I have a csv file that is formatted as follows:

```
1,,3,4
3,4,,0
2,,4,2
```

I'm reading that file into a String variable called text. Then, doing this

```
String newText = text.replaceAll("","0");
```

In my output, it's replacing the no value elements with a 0 which is what I want, but it's also appending a 0 before and after the elements that do have a value.

```
010
0
030
040
030
040
0
000
020
0
040
020
```

Any helps is appreciated !

EDIT: Here is the rest of my code for clairification.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class DataMatrix {

    private double[][] dMatrix; 

    public DataMatrix(String text) {

        String[] line = text.split("\n");
        // Creates an array for the CSV file
        String[][] sMatrix = new String[line.length][];

        for(int i=0; i < line.length; i++)
            sMatrix[i] = line[i].split(",");

        /*for(int j=0; j < sMatrix.length; j++) {
            for(int x=0; x <= line.length; x++) {
                if(sMatrix[j][x] !=*/ 

        System.out.println("Original String: ");

        for(int x=0; x < sMatrix.length; x++) {
            for(int j=0; j <= line.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(sMatrix[x][j]);
            }
        }

        dMatrix = new double[sMatrix.length][];
        System.out.println("Converted to double: ");

        for(int x=0; x < sMatrix.length; x++) {
            dMatrix[x] = new double[sMatrix[x].length];
            for(int j=0; j <= sMatrix.length; j++) {

                dMatrix[x][j] = Double.parseDouble(sMatrix[x][j]);
                System.out.println(dMatrix[x][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void avgRowValue() {

        double tempTotal = 0;

        for(int x=0; x < dMatrix.length; x++) {
            System.out.println("***********************************");
            System.out.println("The average for row "+(x+1)+" is: ");

            for(int i=0; i < dMatrix[x].length;i++) {
                tempTotal += dMatrix[x][i];
            double rowAvg = tempTotal / dMatrix[x].length;
            System.out.println(rowAvg);
            tempTotal = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    public void avgColValue() {

        double tempTotal = 0;

        for(int x=0; x < dMatrix[0].length; x++) {
            System.out.println("**************************************");
            System.out.println("The average for column "+(x+1)+" is: ");

            for(int i=0; i <= dMatrix.length-1; i++)
                tempTotal += dMatrix[i][x];
            double colAvg = tempTotal / dMatrix.length;
            System.out.println(colAvg);
            tempTotal = 0;
        }
    }

    public void overallAvgValue() {

        double tempTotal = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for(int x=0; x < dMatrix.length; x++) {
            for(int i=0; i <= dMatrix.length; i++) {
                tempTotal += dMatrix[x][i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        double overallAvg = tempTotal / count;
        System.out.println("The overall average for the data matrix is: "+overallAvg);
    }

    public void maxValue() {

        double maxValue = 0;

        for(int x=0; x < dMatrix.length; x++) {
            for(int i=0; i <= dMatrix.length; i++) {
                if(dMatrix[x][i] >= maxValue)
                    maxValue = dMatrix[x][i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The max value for the data matrix is: "+maxValue);
    }

    public void minValue() {

        double minValue = dMatrix[0][0];

        for(int x=0; x < dMatrix.length; x++) {
            for(int i=0; i <= dMatrix.length; i++) {
                if(dMatrix[x][i] <= minValue)
                    minValue = dMatrix[x][i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The min value for the data matrix is: "+minValue);
    }
}
```

and my main:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment1{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Make sure the user passed the command line argument - and nothing else
             if (args.length != 1){
                System.out.println("Assignment1 takes exactly one command-line argument.");
                     System.out.println("Usage: java Assignment1 some_file.csv");
                 System.exit(0);
             }

             String csvFileName = args[0];

          //Instantiate my custom file reader
        CSVReader fileReader = new CSVReader();

       //Read the file into a string
        String text = fileReader.readFile(csvFileName);
    String newText = text.replaceAll("", "0");
    //Create a new instance of DataMatrix that takes in String CSV file and converts to double array
    DataMatrix matrix = new DataMatrix(newText);

    boolean done = false;
    while(done != true) {
        System.out.println("**********************");
        System.out.println("CSV Reader Menu: ");
        System.out.println("1. Display the average values of each individual row.");
        System.out.println("2. Display the averages value of each individual column.");
        System.out.println("3. Display the average of the entire data matrix.");
        System.out.println("4. Display the maximum value of the entire data matrix.");
        System.out.println("5. Display the minimum value of the entire data matrix.");
        System.out.println("0. Exit.");

        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: matrix.avgRowValue();
                break;
            case 2: matrix.avgColValue();
                break;
            case 3: matrix.overallAvgValue();
                break;
            case 4: matrix.maxValue();
                break;
            case 5: matrix.minValue();
                break;
            case 0: done = true;
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                break;
        }
    }//end of menu loop
    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Comment: @azurefrog buggy code ...

Comment: @azurefrog a buggy example `,` , output must be : `0 0` , but with your code output is nothing

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @azurefrog ! What I'm trying to do is read through the csv file, and put it into an array (which I have done already). Then, when one of the spots in the csv file has no value and I need to assign a 0 to it.

Comment: you've read that from csv file ? now you have each line in a string ?

Comment: if this is true , then i'll write the true answer

Comment: I would suggest you add a bit more of your code that makes it clear exactly what `text` is.  A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Yes, that is what I have done. I read it in as a string, and split it at the new line character, then split at the "," deliminator. Now have it saved in a 2D array.

Comment: 2D Array ? O_o , if you use string it could be 1D array , if you write it with char array , it can be 2D

Comment: @azurefrog I have updated the post with my code.

Comment: hmm , you don't even take a look into my efficient answer ...

Comment: What's your question? The computer is doing exactly what you told it to do so I see no problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i prefer to do this while reading from csv file , its cost is much less than doing it after reading csv file , so i make a csvreader and an array named `Line` , reading line by line from csv , and if the length of a string is bigger than `0` it written in this mode : `0thatstring0` , otherwise it written as `0`

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] Line;
while ((Line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < Line.length ; i++)
        if(Line[i].length>0) System.out.println(Line[i]);
        else System.out.println("0");
}
```

**second** method , i'm not offering it , is using split method and spliting each string with `","` , do the `replace` method and it works

Comment: Good for using `CSVReader` instead of `split`. But you seem to have misunderstood the requirements. The OP doesn't want 123,,5 to be turned into 01230,0,050. He wants 123,0,5. You need to just print `Line[i]` if `!Line[i].isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 3):

With `text.replaceAll("", "0")` you are looking for all the places where there is a zero-length substring in the string. This is, for any string, between any two characters as well as at the beginning and at the end of the string.

```
"12345".replaceAll("", "_")  // _1_2_3_4_5_
```

If you *really* want to use regex for this, you could use `replaceAll("^$", "0")`, where `^` and `$` are the beginning and the end of the string, respectively. Alternatively, just check whether the string is empty:

```
String newText = text.isEmpty() ? "0" : text;
```

Example:

```
for (String s : "1,,23,4".split(",")) {
    System.out.println(s.isEmpty() ? "0" : s);  // prints 1, 0, 23, and 4
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^$", "0"));// prints 1, 0, 23, and 4
}
```

---

If you want to insert those `0` into the original string, i.e. before using `split`, you could use a disjunction of different regexes for the start-of-string, mid-string, and end-of-string cases, using [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions, e.g. `(?<=^|,)` for "preceded by start-of-string or `,`", and `(?=,|$)` for "followed by `,` or end-of-string":

```
String nums = ",1,,23,4,";
System.out.println(nums.replaceAll("(?<=^|,)(?=,|$)", "0"));
// output: 0,1,0,23,4,0
```

Or you could use capturing groups and group references in the replacement string to carry the `,` over into the replacement. Here, `$10$2` means "1st group, then `0`, then 2nd group":

```
System.out.println(nums.replaceAll("(^|,)(,|$)", "$10$2"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I tried either the replaceAll option or text.isEmpty option I'm getting a number format exception error stating String is empty.

Comment: this is wrong , if my input `123,,5` your answer will be `0102030 0 050 `

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi How comes? You are aware that the first line of code is not my answer but to illustrate what OP's current code is doing, right? How would either of the two ways presented in the lower part produce that output?

Comment: it's ok now :))

Comment: i love your 3 replaceAll Method (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a library such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read that file, then replace the empty cells as you encounter them.  It will be a lot more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `text` contains the value of a single column, after you split the line based on commas. You want to change empty strings into "0".

The `replaceAll()` method takes a *regex*. An empty string is strange for a regex. What you want is `text.replaceAll("^$", "0")`.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi no, and the OP doesn't need to check for `,,`. He has already split the line into separate values. The commas are no longer there.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thanks for your reply. I tried what you stated and it does not replace the empty values with 0 in my output.

Comment: @NickM I see what you've done in the code you pasted in your edit. The `replaceAll()` needs to be on each _field_. Instead, you're trying to apply it to the entire text! You should try calling `replaceAll()` just after your `split(",")` call. If you prefer to apply it to the entire text, then you need to call `replaceAll(",,", ",0,")`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Awesome, that fixed it! I've only been learning Java for maybe 2 months now, so there are some technicalities that I need to learn. Thank you for point it out :)